# Unable set table mapping to Boolean = False

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, table-per-hierarchy

I am trying to set an [inheritance in Entity-Framework](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-1.aspx), I want to set the mapping when BooleanColumn = True.

I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if the Boolean column isn't also a Property.

So make sure you aren't also trying to map that column to a property of the Entity.

Comment: Conclusion: I will wait with this inheritance feature for the next version.